# How to get supervisord to restart hung workers?

Tags: background-process, supervisord, worker

I have a number of Python workers managed by supervisord that should continuously print to stdout (after each completed task) if they are working properly. However, they tend to hang, and we've had difficulty finding the bug. Ideally supervisord would notice that they haven't printed in X minutes and restart them; the tasks are idempotent, so non-graceful restarts are fine. Is there any supervisord feature or addon that can do this? Or another supervisor-like program that has this out of the box?

We are already using http://superlance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/memmon.html to kill if memory usage skyrockets, which mitigates some of the hangs, but a hang that doesn't cause a memory leak can still cause the workers to reach a standstill.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possible solution would be to wrap your python script in a bash script that'd monitor it and exit if there isn't output to stdout for a period of time.

For example:

**kill-if-hung.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

TIMEOUT=60
LAST_CHANGED="$(date +%s)"

{
    set -e
    while true; do
        sleep 1
        kill -USR1 $$
    done
} &

trap check_output USR1

check_output() {
    CURRENT="$(date +%s)"
    if [[ $((CURRENT - LAST_CHANGED)) -ge $TIMEOUT ]]; then
        echo "Process STDOUT hasn't printed in $TIMEOUT seconds"
        echo "Considering process hung and exiting"
        exit 1
    fi
}

STDOUT_PIPE=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo $STDOUT_PIPE

trap cleanup EXIT
cleanup() {
    kill -- -$$ # Send TERM to child processes
    [[ -p $STDOUT_PIPE ]] && rm -f $STDOUT_PIPE
}

$@ >$STDOUT_PIPE || exit 2 &

while true; do
    if read tmp; then
        echo "$tmp"
        LAST_CHANGED="$(date +%s)"
    fi
done <$STDOUT_PIPE
```

Then you would run a python script in supervisord like: `kill-if-hung.sh python -u some-script.py` (`-u` to disable output buffering, or set `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`).

I'm sure you could imagine a python script that'd do something similar.

Comment: Thanks! A lot going on there, and thanks for writing this up! A background process to poll, signaling the main script via a signal; a temporary FIFO to ensure that the main script gets the output of the child; correct signal handling that proxies to the children on any exit (SIGINT and SIGTERM trigger a `trap ___ EXIT` which I just learned!) Should have guessed this was the right way to solve it - it's not necessary for the supervisor to handle all the business logic, if a wrapper script can do it better!